# How this printf works in this program -clarification in c?

Tags: c, printf

Need some clarification...

Why do I get `2.50 0 0 0.0` as output?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float a=5.0,b=2.0;
    printf("%f %d\n",a/b,a/b);
    printf("%d %f",a/b,a/b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing into `int`?

Comment: The mismatched parameters in your printf statements will result in Undefined Behavio(u)r - there is nothing further to explain.

Comment: @Mysticial: Your edit changed the meaning of the question (though both versions have undefined behavior).

Comment: @KeithThompson I think my initial edit crossed with the OP's. I'm 100% sure it was originally `int`. I'll fix that then.

Comment: The edit history says it was originally `float`.

Comment: @CarlNorum Edits (by the OP) within the first 5 min. don't get recorded.

Answer (score 4):

You are causing **undefined behaviour**, since the type of `a/b` is (promoted to) `double`, which does not match the format specifier `%d` (which expects an `int`).

(The reason you see `0` is probably because the `sizeof(int)` bytes you happen to be accessing are all zero, being part of the (very short) mantissa of a simple number like `2.5`, and your platform stores floating point numbers as IEEE754 in little endian order:

```
    |        <-- * -->         // * = sizeof(int)
400 | 4 0000 0000 0000         // == 2.5
S+E | Mantissa
```

Try `2./5.` to see some other results.)

Comment: @CarlNorum: Hm, the question got edited... Now I don't know but the OP's described behaviour suggests that `a/b` gets passed as a double (at least after the variadic standard promotion).